# Loop over indices of sliced array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, slice

I want to loop over the indices of an array starting on the second index. How can I do this?

I have tried:

```sh
myarray=( "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4")
for i in ${!myarray[@]:1}
do
    # I only print the indices to simplify the example
    echo $i 
done
```

But doesn't work.

Obviously this works:

```sh
myarray=( "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4")
myindices=("${!myarray[@]}")
for i in ${myindices[@]:1}
do
    echo $i
done
```

But I would like to combine everything in the for loop statement if possible.

Comment: Please clarify whether the array is indexed or associative.

Comment: It is an indexed array. I added some more code for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **`#`** *parameter length* expansion:

```
myarray=( "test1" "test2" "test3" "test4")
for (( i=1;  i < ${#myarray[@]};  i++ ))
do
    # only print the indices to simplify the example
    echo $i 
done
```

---

Note that the `!` *indirect expansion* operator is evidently not compatible with *substring expansion* since:

```
echo "${!myarray[@]:2}"
```

Produces an error code *1* and outputs to STDERR:

```
bash: test1 test2 test3 test4: bad substitution
```

At least for current versions of `bash`, *v.4.4* and earlier.  Unfortunately `man bash` doesn't make it sufficiently clear that *substring expansion* doesn't work with *indirect expansion*.

Comment: If anyone knows of a `bash` wishlist or feature request bug about making *substring expansion* work with *indirect expansion*, please post a URL.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myarray=('a' 'b' 'c' 'd')

start_index=2
# generate a null delimited list of indexes
printf '%s\0' "${!myarray[@]}" |
  # slice the indexes list 2nd entry to last
  cut --zero-terminated --delimiter='' --fields="${start_index}-" |
  # iterate the sliced indexes list
  while read -r -d '' i; do
    echo "$i"
  done
```

Output does not list first index `0` as expected:

```
1
2
3
```

Works as well with an associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeset -A myassocarray=(["foo"]='a' ["bar"]='b' ["baz"]='c' ["qux"]='d')

start_index=2
# generate a null delimited list of indexes
printf '%s\0' "${!myassocarray[@]}" |
  # slice the indexes list 2nd entry to last
  cut --zero-terminated --delimiter='' --fields="${start_index}-" |
  # iterate the sliced indexes list
  while read -r -d '' k; do
    echo "$k"
  done
```

Output:

```
bar
baz
qux
```

Comment: On my system (*bash v4.4.20*) that associative code outputs: 
`baz
foo
qux` (but the spaces are really `\n`s).  Looking closer, `echo ${!myassocarray[@]}` outputs: `bar baz foo qux` , which implies that `bash` is alphabetizing the index names.

Comment: Related Q: [BASH associative array rearrange keys](https://superuser.com/questions/877299/bash-associative-array-rearrange-keys)

Comment: I think my intentions have been misinterpreted. I want to for-loop over a range from 1 to the last index of an array in the simplest way possible. This outputs the intended result but is not simpler than my already working answer. I was just wondering if it can be done within the for-loop declaration somehow.